# Can't acces a global variable inside a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem that when i try to use a global variable inside a method, an error is produced ("local variable 'b' referenced before assignment").
Why is this not the case when the variable is an element of a list?

this works fine:

```
a = [1]
def a_add():
    a[0] += 1

a_add()
print(a)
```

but this doesn't:

```
b = 1
def b_add():
    b += 1

b_add()
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to assign something to `b` Python does a `LOAD_FAST` which is in relation to locals. You need to add `global b` before trying to use `b`.

```
def b_add():
    global b
    b += 1
```

From the other point of view of:

```
def b_add():
    print(b)
```

Python instead does a `LOAD_GLOBAL` which loads in relation to globals. Thus when you did `a[0]` it first does `LOAD_GLOBAL` for `a` and then subsequently stores the value.

Answer (score 3):

The [official FAQ page](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) has detailed explanation for this error:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def foo():
...     print(x)
...     x += 1
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable. Consequently when the earlier print(x) attempts to print the uninitialized local variable and an error results.

And for code:

```
a = [1]
def a_add():
    a[0] += 1

a_add()
print(a)
```

It just reads value from and assigns value to the first slot of the `global` array, so there's no problem.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you once more :)

Comment: Glad to help @Solim

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to take a deep dive into CPython and see the exact reason why this does not work, check out this link to the CPypthon [ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c) sourcecode file. This is the code that executes the python bytecode.
As Vallentin said, python does a LOAD_FAST bytecode instruction for loading b (see below).

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...     x += 1
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

In the ceval.c file on line 1228 (as of the 30st of May 2019) the relevant code is as follows:

```
case TARGET(LOAD_FAST): {
        PyObject *value = GETLOCAL(oparg);
        if (value == NULL) {
            format_exc_check_arg(tstate, PyExc_UnboundLocalError,
                                 UNBOUNDLOCAL_ERROR_MSG,
                                 PyTuple_GetItem(co->co_varnames, oparg));
            goto error;
```